# Read values from TXT file into CMD file

Tags: cmd

I am trying to do the following:

I have a list of all the computer's service tag, internal number & shelf number.

I want to display the computer's service tag, along with our internal number & shelf number and capture into a log file for our tracking purposes.

The BIOS also has the service tag stored in it, I know if I give a command like

```
if %servicetag%==(here it looks for the same service tag from my text file)
```

If the above numbers match then it can show `service tag` + `internal number` + `shelf number`.

```
For /f  "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /FORMAT:csv') do (set "servicetag=%%i")
```

(I don't know what line to put for pulling the variables from my txt file. the name of my txt file is serverlist.txt) I don't even know how to format the info in my txt file. Please help!!

```
ECHO Comments="Service Tag: %servicetag%">>R:\SYSTEM.LOG
ECHO Comments="Inventory Number: %internalnumber%">>R:\SYSTEM.LOG
ECHO Comments="Shelf Number: %shelfnumber%">>R:\SYSTEM.LOG
```

Comment: What's the exact info you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Completely **edited** due to new information:

```
@echo off
set "servicetag=XCB2MV"        REM for testing only
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%i in ('findstr "%servicetag%" Computerlist.csv') do (
  ECHO Comments="Service Tag: %%i"
  ECHO Comments="Inventory Number: %%j"
  ECHO Comments="Shelf Number: %%k"
)>>R:\SYSTEM.LOG
```

Computerlist.csv

```
BXC4MV,0042,03 
XCB2MV,0043,03 
C4MKQV,0044,04 
ERC9MV,0045,03
```

I named the file `.csv` because this way you can easily open it with Excel. But it's only a simple textfile.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for your reply. I actually don't know myself what format I should keep the format for my txt file.

Example:

BXC4MV 0042 03
XCB2MV 0043 03
C4MKQV 0044 04
ERC9MV 0045 03

Comment: well, that depends, on what you need and how you want to use it. Your comment suggests, there are several computers with tree values each. My tip: one line per computer, separated by `;`. to read, get line until empty, and separate the tokens via `for`. If you use the file for this purpose only, I would write only the data without any tags. But that's only my personal view.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, so in other words, my notepad file should look like

BXC4MV;0042;03
XCB2MV;0043;03
C4MKQV;0044;04
ERC9MV;0045;03